# How to access ServiceStack authentication failure on QueryString

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I've implemented Credentials Authentication using a POST form.

If I enter wrong credentials I get redirected to:

http://localhost:54407/login#f=Invalid+UserName+or+Password

The problem is that I can't access the part after the '#' in my server-side code, and therefore can't display the message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Any Hash params on urls can only be retrieved from the client with JavaScript which can be accessed from `location.hash` and parsed into a variable using `/js/ss-utils.js` with:

```
var hashVars = $.ss.queryString(location.hash.replace('#','?'));
console.log(hashVars.f); //= Invalid UserName or Password
```

You can tell ServiceStack to instead add any redirect params on the querystring with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
   AddRedirectParamsToQueryString = true,
});
```

Which will now redirect to `?f=Invalid+UserName+or+Password`